# Flush snapdragon instruction cache

Tags: android, linux-kernel, arm, cpu-cache, self-modifying

I'm currently writing in-kernel hooker code on snapdragon machine (Nexus 5). My current hooker implementation is here.

https://github.com/perillamint/hideroot/blob/8c66dd8d515e0c8506ec6d229f296a8a1d24f293/gphook.c

I tested this code with Galaxy Note 2 (exynos 4412) and it works(Print Awesome! when sys_open is called. code: https://github.com/perillamint/hideroot/blob/8c66dd8d515e0c8506ec6d229f296a8a1d24f293/main.c). But when I run this code in Nexus 5 (MSM8974), instruction cache seems does not flushed at all.

How can I flush snapdragon's instruction cache?

Comment: Writing 'self-modifying' code is difficult.  Not only do you need to **invalidate** the i-cache, you need to make sure that the d-cache is flushed (from `memcpy()`) and the write buffers have committed the memory.  You need to then **invalidate** the i-cache range.  Look in the cortex-a manuals for **IMB**; for multi-cpu configurations with multiple cache levels, this is more involved than what you currently have.  After you have finished the job of attacking, you should try the more difficult job of defending.

Comment: Update: I tries to clean data cache to Point of Coherence and invalidate instruction cache to Point of Unification. To achive this, I used inline assembly.

Here is code.
https://github.com/perillamint/hideroot/blob/a4f60ded4705c69e417622055740cf70a1b64fb9/gphook.c#L18

My new code works in Exynos 4412, but it still not works in Snapdragon (Nexus 5).

Comment: The Nexus 5 is a [Krait CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krait_%28CPU%29), a custom Cortex-A15 type design by QualComm.  The Exynos chip is a Cortex-A9? and is probably an official design from ARM.  Things like custom flushing code will be different.  You need to look at the TRM for each and make sure the flush sequence is the same. [arm64 mm cache.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm64/mm/cache.S) for example might be in use.  I guess that the QualComm TRM is under NDA and that is why you didn't have a link in your question?